# Filling HashSet in a codeFights task

Tags: java

The goal of my daily task is to count how many groups of integers(from 1 to 10000, 10001 to 20000 etc. till 1000000) in a giving array (int [] a) are represented( as for example, a[0] =2, so it belongs to group 1).

My view on that is like:

```
static int countingGroups(int[] a) 
{
    Set<Integer> setOfGroupsExposed = new HashSet<>();
    // Creating set for counting groups

    List<Integer>list = IntStream.iterate(1,i->i+(1*10000)).limit(101).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //      list.forEach(System.out::println);

    int res = setOfGroupsExposed.size();

    for (int i = 0; i <a.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <list.size() ; j++) {
            if(a[i]>=list.get(j)&& a[i]<list.get(j++))
                setOfGroupsExposed.add(j);
    //          System.out.println(setOfGroupsExposed); - prints just empty brackets


        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

And I can't understand what's wrong with my loops over here, and why Set is always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
if (a[i]>=list.get(j)&& a[i]<list.get(j++))
```

to

```
if (a[i]>=list.get(j)&& a[i]<list.get(j+1))
```

otherwise you increment `j` twice in each iteration, and besides, `j++` returns the original value of `j`, so your condition has the same effect as `if (a[i]>=list.get(j)&& a[i]<list.get(j))`.

Comment: Science bless you!